# ¿Porque no encuentra mi pagina con la direccion de localhost? laravel

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform

estoy haciendo una pagina web para mi proyecto de mi universidad, estoy haciendo uso de la api de Google para poder iniciar sesión en mi aplicación usando `Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();` he seguido los pasos de tutoriales de YouTube, pero yo tengo un problema y es que yo no puedo acceder a mi aplicación con la ruta del localhost, tengo que usar mi virtualhost que cree para mi pagina, pero este no me deja poner en la consola de Google como ruta de redirección , entonces mi duda es, como puedo hacer para acceder a mi aplicación usando la ruta de localhost para hacer pruebas de inicio de sesión??

aqui les dejo un ejemplo de como encuentra las rutas y mis rutas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui mis rutas:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
 });

Route::get('/logIn', [LoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login.show');
Route::post('/logIn', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('login');

   Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
   Route::get('/redirect', [LoginController::class, 'redirect'])->name('google.auth');
   Route::get('/callback', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('google.callback');
});
Route::post('/logOut', [LoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
```

Comment: A que url estas accediendo en el navegador? Apenas se ve en la imagen... pero probablemente tengas que apuntar el root del servidor al directorio `/public` de tu proyecto laravel

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ hola, estoy accediendo a la ruta: localhost/foroweb/public/auth/redirect

Comment: Te sugiero configurar tu servidor como te mencioné antes, para que la url te quede así `localhost/auth/redirect`

Comment: Podes ver un ejemplo de como sería con nginx en la doc https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/deployment#server-configuration